# Usercontrol is getting selected unnecessarily on Keydown Specifically for F10

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to capture key down and do some functionality when (F10) key is pressed.
This works first time but when i press again the whole usercontrol is getting selected. So now i have to press the (F10) twice to trigger the keydown.
Any possible reasons why i am not able to trigger or get the keydown.?

I have a tree user control left side and i have a detail section user control on right side. On treeviewitem selection the respective data will be loaded on right side usercontrol. On Key down the right side detail section is getting selected as i could see the dotted lines on the detail section user control. 
I am able to capture all keys other than F10

Comment: As far as I am aware no one here is a mind reader, please show the relevant code.

Comment: sorry if i was not clear . this is nothing to do with the code. I could just find that F10 is a system key which launches the window menu. It's the same in all Windows apps.@TheLethalCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33821c88-4246-485a-8ac7-eee921ab3864/wpf-what-is-f10-doing-to-my-key-trapping?forum=wpf

F10 is a system key which launches the window menu. It's the same in all Windows apps.